# How to only parse 1 JSONObject in Swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, parsing

I'm using Swift 5 to make an iOS app that interacts with an API based on the user's locale. I'm currently having issues only parsing one JSONObject, rather than parsing/printing the results of all JSONObjects in the array. In other words, I'd like to get a key/value pair based on another key/value pair. The endpoint I'm using is https://covid19api.herokuapp.com/confirmed. I'm trying to get the user's country code with this snippet (which works, no problems there):

```
import Foundation

let locale = NSLocale.current

func requestLocale() -> String {
    return(locale.regionCode!)
}
```

And I need to search within a JSONObject that contains that country code for an item called `latest`. Here's my code for the API Request (This returns some data I have put below the code):

```
import Foundation

struct WorldWide: Decodable {
    let latest: Int
    let locations: [Country]
}
struct Country: Decodable {
    let country_code: String = "\(requestLocale())"
    let latest: Int
}

func APIRequest() {
    guard let url = URL(string: "https://covid19api.herokuapp.com/confirmed") else {fatalError("Could not get data from the API")}
    let session = URLSession.shared
    session.dataTask(with: url) {(data, response, error) in
        guard let data = data else {return}
        do {
            let decoded = try JSONDecoder().decode(WorldWide.self, from: data)
            print(decoded)
        } catch {print(error)}
    }.resume()
}
```

Keep in mind the first `latest` within `WorldWide` is at the top level, while the JSONObjects are within an array called `locations` and each JSONObject contains a `latitude`, `longitude`, `country`, `country_code`, `history`, and `latest` (I'm not using camelCase because the dataset doesn't). All I need to access are the `country_code`, which I have from the user's locale, and the `latest`, which I need to get ONLY from the JSONObject that contains the `country_code`.

Running the above code will give me this:

```
WorldWide(latest: 1426096, locations: [Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 423), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 383), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 1468), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 545), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 17), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 19), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 1628), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 853), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 96), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 2686), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 28), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 934), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 411), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 89), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 1191), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 460), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 12639), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 717), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 33), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 811), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 164), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 63), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 861), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 22194), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 26), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 5), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 194), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 764), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 14034), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 135), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 577), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 384), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 7), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 115), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 658), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 1373), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 1266), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 13), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 217), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 105), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 228), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 310), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 4726), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 22), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 9340), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 260), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 8), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 10), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 5116), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 990), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 587), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 579), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 351), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 139), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 1533), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 254), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 146), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 168), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 327), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 544), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 1276), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 935), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 67803), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 1019), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 121), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 651), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 937), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 98), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 144), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 44), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 75), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 18), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 256), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 781), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 538), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 138), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 560), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 180), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 1), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 76), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 184), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 1265), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 1780), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 45), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 180), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 483), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 349), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 1282), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 712), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 396), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 494), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 5017), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 184), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 11), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 5071), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 90), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 1956), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 3747), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 1450), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 78), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 16), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 31), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 1149), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 10), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 52), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 15), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 2308), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 72), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 47), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 139), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 171), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 18), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 358), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 6), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 32), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 152), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 109069), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 30), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 4), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 196), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 107663), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 287), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 1832), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 77), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 144), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 33), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 25), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 7), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 305), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 817), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 1586), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 5311), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 2738), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 62589), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 1122), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 5709), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 9248), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 135586), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 63), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 3906), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 353), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 697), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 172), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 10331), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 743), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 228), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 548), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 548), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 14), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 78), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 880), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 2970), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 88), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 3963), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 19), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 293), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 6), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 268), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 2439), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 1056), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 79), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 15), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 241), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 1184), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 16), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 9), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 74), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 13), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 40), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 19580), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 1160), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 6), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 278), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 254), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 599), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 6086), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 371), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 4035), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 2100), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 2), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 115), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 2954), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 3764), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 4848), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 12442), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 2057), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 4417), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 7497), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 105), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 14), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 8), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 279), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 2795), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 237), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 2447), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 11), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 1481), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 581), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 1059), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 8), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 1749), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 141942), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 185), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 14), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 10), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 7693), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 22253), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 376), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 24), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 2258), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 65), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 107), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 623), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 34109), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 52), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 1462), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 2359), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 39), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 45), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 335), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 113), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 150), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 9), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 55242), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 424), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 396223), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 520), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 165), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 249), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 39), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 11), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 0), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 15), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 12), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 10), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 19), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 1), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 7), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 0), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 14), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 20), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 261), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 33), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 56), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 11), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 5), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 7), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 170), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 22), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 3), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 3), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 8), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 9), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 6), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 3), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 6), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 2), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 8), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 2), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 1), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 2), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 4), Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 4)])
```

I looked back through the dataset, and what I'm getting here is the program printing **every** instance of `latest` and just pairing it with the `country_code` that I provided. 
Basically I need to do

```
if country_code == requestLocale() {
    print(latest)
}
```

But this isn't exactly what would work, it's just a theory.
If someone could walk me through this, that would be great!

Comment: So, to keep it clear: `let allLocations = decoded.locations`, and filter `allLocations.country_code`, if so, use `filter()`: `let targetLocations = allLocations.filter({ $0.countryCode == requestLocale() })`?

Comment: Adding `let allLocations = decoded.locations; let targetLocations = allLocations.filter({ $0.country_code == requestLocale() }); print(targetLocations)` returns the same data, even when `print(decoded)` is commented out.

Comment: `let country_code: String = "\(requestLocale())" => `let country_code: String` because else you are setting default value and not reading the one in the response JSON

Comment: I did that and it worked, however it returned `[Dark.Country(country_code: "US", latest: 607670)] ` and I cannot do something like `print(targetLocations.Dark.Country.latest)` to only return that one Int. How would I go about only getting that 1 Int (607670) so I can show it to the user in a UILabel?

Comment: `let targetLatest = allLocations.first.latest`?

Comment: The only problem with that is that it prints the `first` value rather than the desired one from the user's locale. So I cant get the first value, I need to get the 33rd or the 15th or the 42nd, and it all depends on the user's locale. It seems very complicated to keep adding code to find the position and change `first` to the index of the user's country like `let targetLatest = allLocations.indexOfPosition.latest`

Comment: I meant targetLocations.fisrt.latest

Comment: that still doesnt work, I need to get a specific value rather than just the first one.